# Is there a way to console log the amount of firebase firestore reads in react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, console.log

Im creating a react app using firebase firestore on the backend. Yesterday my app started acting weird kinda randomly (it's never really random tho is it?...) and I maxed out the total number of allowed reads on the free tier which is 50,000 reads!!!

I already understand the concept of how reads work.. I just need to know if there is a way to console.log firestore reads so I can narrow down on what db call or function is responsible for the ginormous amount of reads.

Just to give a little insight, Im using functional components and I believe it may have to do with a useEffect function I've written somewhere... PLEASE HELP lol!!

Comment: This is a good reason why I tend to write barely-there wrappers around most database functions - that way you can add things like console.log, console.trace, etc right at call.

Comment: There's no trivial *native* way that I know of, although examining your code in the console (Source) might let you leverage some breakpoints you can step through to find internal point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is **not directly** BUT you can insert a console.log inside the firestore db call function and if it prints a bajillion times, you'll know that you're consistently fetching data from firestore... this is how I figured it out. Hope this helps someone.